# What is the exact way to get Devil Deal Rooms?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I know the typical rule that if you don't lose any hearts (or red hearts if you have red AND white/silver/black hearts) you can get a Devil Deal Room after a boss fight, but something odd happened the last time I played.

I was playing as Eve (with the curse activated) and I only had the standard 3 red hearts. So I was battling one of those snake thing bosses on the first floor (with both the curse and Monstro's Lung which I had gotten earlier) and I lost a whole heart at one point but I still got a Devil Deal Room.

I don't know if I got it because I defeated it pretty fast or because the Eve character just has that attribute, but I'd like to know why so I can strategize when I play again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

According to the *Rebirth wikia*, there is only a 1% base chance for the [Devil Room](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Devil_Room#Conditions_to_make_Devil_Rooms_appear) door to open. This chance can be increased in various ways:

[image: Devil Room chances]

This means that if you get damaged (this regards ONLY red hearts) during the boss fight you only decrease the chance to open a *Devil Room*, but there's still a small chance to find it anyway.

Comment: Was planing almost this exact answer, but took too long in thinking how to repesent the content from the wiki nicely here ;)

Comment: @djsmiley2k LOL, I thought that a screenshot would have been a good solution :)

Comment: It's perfect, just didn't occur to me :D

Answer (score 1):

With pinckermans answer you know what factors influence your chances. But there is a handy overlay for Rebirth, which displays your current chance for a devil or angel deal (+ your other relevant stats).

It updates live, right when you pick up items, take damage etc. It's not really a mod, so it won't disable any achivements.

[Link to the GitHub overview page](https://github.com/networkMe/missinghud2)

[Link to the released versions](https://github.com/networkMe/missinghud2/releases)

[image: Example screen]

Comment: Good idea, I was thinking the same.